# How to check for a string format in python?

Tags: python, regex

I would like to check for string "tDDDDD" where D has to be digits and should not be more than the length (minimum 4, maximum 5) of it.

No other characters allowed.

Currently my code checks like this,

```
m = re.match('^(t)(\d+)', changectx.branch())
```

But is also allows t12345anythingafterit.

I changed the regular expression to

```
'^(t)(\d\d\d\d)(\d)?$'
```

Is this correct or any smart way of doing it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your regular expression will work, but you could also use this regular expression:

```
r'^t\d{4,5}$'
```

The `{4,5}` is a quantifier that means the previous token must occur between 4 and 5 times.

The parentheses are only necessary here if you wish to capture the matching parts of the string.

Answer (score 2):

how about this regex:

```
r'^t\d{4,5}$'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `re.findall('^(t\d{4,5})', "t1234")`  where regex - `^(t\d{4,5})`

> {m,n}    Matches from m to n repetitions of the preceding RE.

Since you say the digits are a min of 4 and a max of 5 here, m=4 & n=5.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
>>> x="t12345anythingafterit."
>>> re.findall("^t\d{4,5}$",x)
[]
>>> x="t12345"
>>> re.findall("^t\d{4,5}$",x) 
['t12345']
>>> x="t1234"
>>> re.findall("^t\d{4,5}$",x)
['t1234']
>>> x="t123"
>>> re.findall("^t\d{4,5}$",x) 
[]
```